# Euler Brick - Saunderson parametric solution

Tags: pythagorean-triples

Saunderson found a parametric solution giving Euler bricks:

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a pythagoran triple, then we get an Euler brick $(a,b,c)$ with
$a=x(4y^2-z^2)$,
$b=y(4x^2-z^2)$,
$c=4xyz$.

It is claimed, that the parametric solution is not giving all possible Euler bricks- but why? (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerBrick.html)

Can you think of any example? And maybe a proof why that example is not given by the parametric solution?

Comment: Have you seen this [document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.13285.pdf) ?

Comment: The MathWorld page 2nd smallest brick $(275,252,240)$ is not of the parametric form.

Answer (score 1):

With $x^2+y^2=z^2$, $a=x(4y^2-z^2)$, and $b=y(4x^2-z^2)$, it is easy to show that, for the face diagonal $d_{ab}$, one has ${d_{ab}}^2=a^2+b^2=z^6$, hence $d_{ab}=z^3$ is necessarily a perfect cube.

If such parametrization could give all Euler Bricks, then all Euler Bricks would have a perfect cube in one of its face diagonals. But it is not the case. Any Euler Brick without a perfect cube in its face diagonals is not given by such parametrization.